# Arrangement of triangles via tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-shape

**Task:**

I am trying to arrange four triangles via TikZ.

**Below, you see the output:**
[image]

As you can see, I face **two problems** with my solution:

A) It seems hand-made since the borders do not fit perfectly to each other.

B) It is not scaleable because nodes are (manually) fixed to a certain triangle-node.

**MWE and my attempt:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180}],
\tikzstyle{triangle}=[draw, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
size=8cm], 
\node [triangle][fill=gray!15](1) at (0,0) {Content};
\node [triangle][fill=gray!15] (2) [below left=2.5cm and 0cm of 1] {Content A};
\node [triangle] [fill=blue!15] (3) [below right=2.5cm and 0cm of 1] {Content B};
\node [triangle] [fill=gray!15] [border rotated, below=0cm of 1, align=center] {Content C};
\node (11) [above=0.3cm of 1] {Content D};
\node  (21) [below left=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 2] {Content E};
\node (31) [below right=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 3] {Content F};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Please show me how to improve those two issues! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such "precision positioning" it is sometimes advantageous to make use of the anchors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180},
triangle/.style={draw, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
size=8cm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}] 
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15](1) {Content};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,anchor=north] (2) at (1.210) {Content A};
\node [triangle,fill=blue!15,anchor=north] (3) at (1.-30) {Content B};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,border rotated,below=0pt of 1] (4)  {Content C};
\node (11) [above=0.3cm of 1] {Content D};
\node  (21) [below left=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 2] {Content E};
\node (31) [below right=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 3] {Content F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that your figure is a bit wide (I did not change anything) and `\tikzstyle` is deprecated (so I used the same syntax as you already had for `border rotated`).

You may decrease minimum width until you go below a certain scale at which you see the impacts of `Content` having a smaller width than `Content A`, i.e. at which the minimum width is no longer attained for all triangles. So `minimum size=5cm` works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180},
triangle/.style={draw, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
size=5cm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}] 
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15](1) {Content};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,anchor=north] (2) at (1.210) {Content A};
\node [triangle,fill=blue!15,anchor=north] (3) at (1.-30) {Content B};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,border rotated,below=0pt of 1] (4)  {Content C};
\node (11) [above=0.3cm of 1] {Content D};
\node  (21) [below left=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 2] {Content E};
\node (31) [below right=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 3] {Content F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but `minimum size=4cm` does not

[image]

because the `minimum size` is not the actual size.

You *may* go lower by using negative distances for `inner sep`,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180},
triangle/.style={draw, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
size=3.5cm,inner sep=-1.2cm,outer sep=0pt}] 
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15](1) {Content};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,anchor=north] (2) at (1.210) {Content A};
\node [triangle,fill=blue!15,anchor=north] (3) at (1.-30) {Content B};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,border rotated,below=0pt of 1] (4)  {Content C};
\node (11) [above=0.3cm of 1] {Content D};
\node  (21) [below left=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 2] {Content E};
\node (31) [below right=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 3] {Content F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but if you go to `2.5cm` instead of `3.5cm`, the texts won't fit any more

[image]

You can then still scale everything in order to arrive at `2.5cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180},
triangle/.style={draw, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
size=3.5cm,inner sep=-1.2cm,outer sep=0pt},scale=5/7,transform shape] 
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15](1) {Content};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,anchor=north] (2) at (1.210) {Content A};
\node [triangle,fill=blue!15,anchor=north] (3) at (1.-30) {Content B};
\node [triangle,fill=gray!15,border rotated,below=0pt of 1] (4)  {Content C};
\node (11) [above=0.3cm of 1] {Content D};
\node  (21) [below left=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 2] {Content E};
\node (31) [below right=0.3cm and 0.3cm of 3] {Content F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please feel free to improve the graphic as you want. Excited for your suggestions! :-) I also want to make it smaller (like 2.5 cm per triangle)

Comment: @Jens I added a few options that allow you to scale the thing down without messing it up, and commented on potential caveats.